# Symfony/Doctrine: Fallback to default culture for i18n content

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am building a multilingual website with Symfon 1.4/Doctrine, having English language defined as primary.
Content translation in other languages are added gradually, and there will very often be situations when translation of the content requested will be unavailable in requested language. I want to display the requested content in English in those cases.
Is this achievable at global level, e.g. for all the i18n content?

As pointed by Grad van Horck, this works fine by default for interface translation.
What I need is the same functionality for content stored in DB (models having "actAs i18n" behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The default way allows perfectly for this. Just make sure all your texts are in English by default, and translate them where needed. So just do `<?php echo __('Hello'); ?>`, and then translate it if you want. If a translation can't be found, it just falls back at it's 'original'.

To do the same in your database, you'd probably be best of copying the i18n behaviour (Template/Listener) and add your own bit of logic to fall back on English.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean how to do the same for content in DB. Edited my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set the default culture on sfDoctrineRecord (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5458)

```
sfDoctrineRecord::setDefaultCulture('nl'); // default = 'en'
```

This changes the i18n fallback when the translation isn't available in the database.

Comment: this isn't the proper way :), by default it uses the 'sf_default_culture' set in settings.yml as I now see. However what's a bit confusing is the use of a normalized culture eg. 'en' vs 'en_EN' what is eventually the same culture but used mixed also in the symfony docs...